# Single array argument versus multiple arguments in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, arguments

```
public function setSomething($what){
  $this->something = $what;
}

...

$obj->setSomething(array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'));
```

or

```
public function setSomething(){
  $this->something = array_values(func_get_args());
}

...

$obj->setSomething('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
```

Which method would you use and why?

ps: the second one could also be used to emulate keys I think, if you give out argument names:

```
$obj->setSomething($key1 = 'aaa', $key = 'bbb', $key = 'ccc');
```

Comment: How are you getting the data that you're passing to the setter?

Comment: In general, use a function signature that conveys your API to the developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually only use an array if multiple arguments are optional. For example, if I have a report that can take a company ID, an employee ID, or both. I won't have `function report ($CompanyID = null, $EmployeeID = null)`, I'll do `function report($array)` and then inside the function, do `if (isset($array['company_id']))...` etc.

If you think you need to use an array because you have too many arguments, that's probably a sign that the function is too complicated and needs to be split up.

Edit: Note that this is more a general answer, as I'm not sure how it applies to your setter issue, since logically a setter should only take one argument. In your situation, if your `$this->something` expects an array, give it an array, rather than arguments that you have to then turn into an array.